# springboot: config in "additional-location" was overrided by "application-{profile}"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

It is a simple springboot project. only has a few properties and a `MainClass`:

```java
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @Value("${test}")
    String test;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void print() {
        log.info(test);
    }
}
```

It just print the value of variable `test`.

I configure  `test` in `application.properties`:

```
test=test normal

spring.profiles.active=dev
```

The variable was overrided by `application-dev.properties`:

```
test=test in dev
```

Then I run the application, It works. It print: `test in dev`

**The next thing is problem**:

I package the application as a **jar**, and I want to override the `test` when I run this application, So I write a file `out.properties`:

```
test=test in out
```

Start the application by command

```
java -jar target/demo.jar --spring.config.additional-location=out.properties
```

**It still prints `test in dev`!**

I change the command to:

```
java -jar target/demo.jar --test="test in command"
```

It print `test in command`.

I have read the document: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config.
But I didn't find some useful tip.

My purpose is replace some property in application with a out config, so I don't have to change the source code and repackage.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [linked documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) specifically lists the **priority order** of property sources:

1-3. ...

4. Command line arguments.

5-11. ...

12. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
13. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
14. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
15. Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).

16-17. ...

As your code already showed you, (4) `--test="test in command"` overrides anything in (12-15) property files.

You can also see that (12-13) *profile-specific* application property files always override (14-15) *non-profile* application property files.

So, if you want an *external* file to override a (13) *packaged* profile-specific application property file, then you must place that property in a (12) *external* profile-specific application property file.

But, as the note in section [2.4. Profile-specific Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) says:

> If you have specified any **files** in `spring.config.location`, profile-specific variants of those files are not considered. **Use directories** in `spring.config.location` if you want to also use profile-specific properties.

Said another way, any *file* listed in `spring.config.location` is by definition a (14) application property file, regardless of how it is named, so (12-13) profile-specific application property files will override them, whether (13) packaged or (12) external.

***Summary:*** Move the `test=test in out` property to an `application-dev.properties` file in a *directory* listed in the `--spring.config.additional-location` path.